# Frame environment with fixed size given by numbers of characters and lines

Tags: fonts, environments, framed

I would like to make one framed environment with the following behavior.

1. Only the last 8 lines of the content must be displayed. If the content have more than 8 lines, a gentle warning must be produced by LaTeX.
2. The width of the frame is exactly equal to 16 letters.
3. A fixed width font must be used.
4. The content cannot contain formulas. If it is the case, an error must be sent.

This is for imitate the screen of one calculator.

The following solution nearly works except that I would like a better symetric spacing between the content and the box.

[image]

What are the changes to do ?

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{adjustbox}
    \usepackage{color}

% For tests
    \usepackage{comment}


    \makeatletter
        \catcode`\$=\active
        \newenvironment{calculator}{%
            \ttfamily
            \let\(\calculator@error
            \let\[\calculator@error
            \let\array\calculator@error
            % etc.
            \catcode`\$=\active
            \let$\calculator@error
            \begin{lrbox}{\@tempboxa}%
            \minipage[b]{8em}%
        }{%
            \endminipage
            \end{lrbox}%
            \par\smallskip
            % Measure height and clip if required
            \ifdim\ht\@tempboxa>8\baselineskip
                \PackageWarning{calculator}{%
                    calculator environment to long%
                }%
                % clip to only show the 8 last lines:
                \fbox{\clipbox*{0pt {\depth} {\width} 7.5\baselineskip}{%
                    \usebox\@tempboxa
                }}%
            \else
                \fbox{\usebox\@tempboxa}%
            \fi
            \smallskip
        }
        \catcode`\$=3

        \newcommand{\calculator@error}{%
            \PackageError{calculator}{%
                No math is allowed inside calculator environment%
            }{}%
        }

        \newcommand{\tiFocus}[1]{%
            \hspace{-\fboxsep}%
            \colorbox{black}{\textcolor{white}{#1}}%
            \hspace{-\fboxsep}%
        }
    \makeatother


\begin{document}

\section*{8 lines}

\begin{calculator}
\tiFocus{1 3 5 7 9 B D F}
.2 4 6 8 A C E
1 3 5 7 9 B D F
.2 4 6 \tiFocus{8} A C E
1 3 5 7 9 B D F
.2 4 6 8 A C E
1 3 5 7 9 B D F
.2 4 6 8 A C E
\end{calculator}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT: Sorry I used the new version which is currently not available on CTAN. I think in the next days the upload will be finished.

To compile please use the version of [github mdframed](https://github.com/marcodaniel/mdframed)

If you want to use `mdframed` here a solution:

I used the math error macro of Martin.

@Martin: I hope it's ok.

EDIT 2: Changed the detection of math inside the environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paper=a5paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage[skipabove=\topskip,skipbelow=\topskip]{mdframed}
\makeatletter
\newif\ifmathinside\mathinsidefalse
\def\IfContainsMathMode{%
  \ifmathinside
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo%
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo%
  \fi%
  }


\preto\detected@md@put@frame{%
 \IfContainsMathMode{\calculator@error}{}
   \ifdimless{\ht\@tempboxa}{8\baselineskip}
    {}{%
    \splitmaxdepth\z@ \splittopskip\z@
    \dimen@=\dimexpr\ht\@tempboxa-7.9\baselineskip\relax
    \setbox0\vsplit\@tempboxa to \z@
    \setbox\tw@\vsplit\@tempboxa to \dimen@
    \setbox\@tempboxa\vbox{\unvbox0\unvbox\@tempboxa}
    \md@reset
    }%
}
\newcommand{\calculator@error}{%
    \PackageWarning{calculator}{%
        No math is allowed inside calculator environment\MessageBreak%
    }%
}

\newenvironment{calculator}{%
  \begin{mdframed}[linecolor=red,%innerleftmargin=0pt,innerrightmargin=0pt,%
                   settings={\ttfamily\everymath={\global\mathinsidetrue}\sloppy},
                   userdefinedwidth=\dimexpr8em+20.8pt\relax,
                   ]%
 }%
 {%
  \end{mdframed}
  \global\mathinsidefalse
}
\begin{document}


8 lines:

\begin{calculator}

1 3 5 7 9 B D F 
.2 4 6 8 A C E 
1 3 5 7 9 B D F 
.2 4 6 8 A C E 
1 3 5 7 9 B D F 
.2 4 6 8 A C E 
1 3 5 7 9 B D F 
.2 4 6 8 A C E 
\end{calculator}

% 
9 lines:
\begin{calculator}
.5 5 5 5 5 C E 
.2 4 6 8 A C E 
1 3 5 7 9 B D F 
.2 4 6 8 A C E 
1 3 5 7 9 B D F 
.2 4 6 8 A C E 
1 3 5 7 9 B D F 
.2 4 6 8 A C E 
.4 4 4 4 A C E 
\end{calculator}



8 lines:
\begin{calculator}
1 3 5 7 9 B D F 
.2 4 6 8 A C E 
1 3 5 7 9 B D F 
.2 4 6 8 A C E 
1 3 5 7 9 B D F 
.2 4 6 8 A C E 
1 3 5 7 9 B D F 
.2 4 6 8 A C E 
\end{calculator}
math:
\begin{calculator}
1 3 5 7 9 B D F
.2 4 6 8 A C E
1 \(a+b\) B D F
.2 4 6 8 A C E
1 $a+b$  B D F
.2 4 6 8 A C E
1 \[i+b\] B D F
.2 4 6 8 A C E
\end{calculator}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks but my compilation gives the following error : `! LaTeX Error: \begin{mdframed} on input line 94 ended by \end{calculator}.`.

Comment: @projetmbc: I edited my post

Comment: @projetmbc: Please wait some minutes. At the moment I am working on the code to improve the behavior.

Comment: @projetmbc: I edited the code. First I thought the `Underfull \hbox (badness 10000)` based on `mdframed` but it based on the font. At the moment I have no idea to reduce the boxes.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the following steps to achieve the wanted behaviour:

1. can be done by boxing and measuring the content. Overlong boxes can be clipped and a warning can be issued. Either the `collectbox` or `adjustbox` package can help you with this. Not that cropping multiple lines is not without
   risks. You can also use some lower level TeX code to make TeX break after 8 lines and then discard the rest yourself, but this is more complicated (at least for me).
2. Wrap it in a `{minipage}{8em}` environment should do it. You need to test if the width is OK, but for mono-space font it should be.
3. Add `\ttfamily` (before the `minipage`, so that `16em` gives you the `tt` value)
4. You can locally redefine common math macros (`$`, `\[`, `\(`, ...) to produce an error.

I assume here that the content does not have to break over page borders.

The following should do it:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{adjustbox}

\makeatletter
\catcode`\$=\active
\newenvironment{calculator}{%
    \ttfamily
    \let\(\calculator@error
    \let\[\calculator@error
    \let\array\calculator@error
    % etc.
    \catcode`\$=\active
    \let$\calculator@error
    \begin{lrbox}{\@tempboxa}%
    \minipage[b]{8em}%
}{%
    \endminipage
    \end{lrbox}%
    \par\smallskip
    % Measure height and clip if required
    \ifdim\ht\@tempboxa>8\baselineskip
        \PackageWarning{calculator}{%
            calculator environment to long%
        }%
        % clip to only show the 8 last lines:
        \fbox{\clipbox*{0pt {\depth} {\width} 7.5\baselineskip}{%
            \usebox\@tempboxa
        }}%
    \else
        \fbox{\usebox\@tempboxa}%
    \fi
    \par\smallskip
}
\catcode`\$=3

\newcommand{\calculator@error}{%
    \PackageError{calculator}{%
        No math is allowed inside calculator environment%
    }{}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

8 lines:
\begin{calculator}
 1 3 5 7 9 B D F
 .2 4 6 8 A C E
 1 3 5 7 9 B D F
 .2 4 6 8 A C E
 1 3 5 7 9 B D F
 .2 4 6 8 A C E
 1 3 5 7 9 B D F
 .2 4 6 8 A C E
\end{calculator}

9 lines:
\begin{calculator}
 1 3 5 7 9 B D F
 .2 4 6 8 A C E
 1 3 5 7 9 B D F
 .2 4 6 8 A C E
 1 3 5 7 9 B D F
 .2 4 6 8 A C E
 1 3 5 7 9 B D F
 .2 4 6 8 A C E
 1 3 5 7 9 B D F
\end{calculator}

math:
\begin{calculator}
 1 3 5 7 9 B D F
 .2 4 6 8 A C E
 1 \(a+b\) B D F
 .2 4 6 8 A C E
 1 $a+b$  B D F
 .2 4 6 8 A C E
 1 \[i+b\] B D F
 .2 4 6 8 A C E
\end{calculator}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Is there a way to display only the last, and not the first 8 lines ?

Comment: @projetmbc: That's actually easier. I updated my question to do it.

Comment: Is ther one possibility to use the `mdframed` instead of standard boxes ?

Comment: Using `mdframed` after saving the content in a box gives you no benefits. You would need to use some `mdframed` settings or code to make it clip the content for you. I don't now the internals of this package good enough.

Comment: There is one little thing to do. I would like a better symetric spacing between the content and the box. What are the changes to do ?

Comment: @projetmbc: Sorry, you mean the vertical spaces between the framed box and the text before and after? This looks symmetric to me. You can always change the `\smallskip` with `\vspace{<length>}`. There should be a `\par` after the content as well.

Comment: I've uploaded one picture showing the horizontal dissymmetry.

Comment: @projetmbc: That's because I accidently only used 15 (1-F) not 16 (0-F) characters, so the line ends with a space. If you use 16 letters is looks fine to me. But you should use `\hspace*` instead of `\hspace` for the first one in `\tiFocus`, so that the space is even removed if it happens at the begin of the line. Also, you might need to play with the 8em factor a little.